# invalid syntax for print in python3 on jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using python3 kernel on jupyter notebook and I keep getting this error:

```
for line in process.stdout:
    print("\r" + line.strip(), end='', flush=True)
```

And the error message is

```
print(line.strip(), end='', flush=True)
                      ^   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried updating jupyter notebook by
`sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall jupyter`
but didn't do anything.

[image]

Comment: You think you're using Python 3, but that error says you're not.

Comment: @user2357112 is right, you are using python2

Comment: hmm jupyter kernel says python3 on the top right corner... How can I check if it is using python3 kernel?

Comment: `print(sys.version)`

Comment: You are using a Python2 kernel named "Python 3".

Comment: @user2357112 yep you guys are correct. This was due to anaconda2. Deleting anaconda2 made it work. It's very confusing since jupyter notebook calls it python3 kernel